# How do I trigger a route manually with React router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

As the title says, I have a table. If I click on a td, I'd like to forward the user to a specific url.

Now I need to pass an object to the component that will be rendered.

- How do I pass props to a component dynamically?
- How can I manually trigger a route?

I'm on React 0.14.6 and react-router 1.0.3.

My config is pretty straight:

```
<Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
      <Route path='/' component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={SearchCustomer}/>
        <Route path='customerOverview/:props' component={CustomerOverview}/>
      </Route>
    </Router>
  </Provider>
```

customerOverview needs to be triggered onClick with the props being parsed to the componentn.

Comment: have you tried to use *Link to={your url}*? [source](https://github.com/rackt/react-router)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passed props can be accessed from `this.props.route`:

```
this.props.route.yourCustomProp
```

You can programatically go to a new route with `this.props.history` using the normal History module methods like [push](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history#navigation) and [replace](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history#navigation):

```
this.props.history.push('/login')
```

If you need to access the history prop deeper in your component you can use the [withRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) HOC.

For DOM links use [Link](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link) as per docs.

Note this answer has been updated for react-router v4. Old versions of react-router use an older history module which has [pushState and replaceState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) on it.

Comment: This is actually incorrect. The function signature of the pushState method is (state object, title, url) with "the title currently ignored" https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Comment: Thanks I think this was a little out of date I've updated it as the history prop uses the history package which has 'push' and 'replace' which take 1-2 params